# How can I get rid of the lines around my hots spots?

Tags: masking, outline

I have drawn a hotspot link ontop of an image, but unfortunaltely I can see the actual outlines in the web browser SAFARI. Is there a way of getting rid of this? I use Dreamweaver CS3 on a Mac.

[On this web page](http://www.casanovawatertaxi.com/snap/exhibitions.html), I've drawn the hotspot links arond the image of the rabbits and the yellow circle. You can see that when you click on these links, you see the area I have drawn the hotspot.

Greatful for any help. Thank you,
Vanessa

Comment: Usually a link is 'outlined' when selected, in any browser. Are you seeing an outline before it is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `outline:none;` css style.

You'll want to apply that to your link styles for that image.

EDIT: Add this in your style tags at the top of the page:

```
map area{
outline:none;
}
```

So it should look like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
@import url(../css_snap01.css);
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
map area{
outline:none;
}
-->
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks Grillz, I'm not fluent in CSS. Do you know where I shall insert your code? I wanted to copy in the html code here, but the forum won;t allow me. Many Thanks.

Comment: @user1106852 Updated my answer to show where to enter the code